# Why do two calculations give different answers?

Tags: c, floating-point, constants, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define pi1 3.141

const float pi = 3.141;

int main()    
{    
    printf("%f %f", 4 * 10 * pi, 4 * 10 * pi1); 
}
```

Output (on my machine) is `125.639999 125.640000`

Comment: what output did you get?

Comment: Output (on my machine) is `125.639999 125.640000`

Comment: My previous comment used `gcc -03`. If I ***drop*** the `-O3`, I get `125.640001 125.640000`. gcc version is 4.1.2.

Answer (score 5):

pi1 is a preprocessor symbol and is replaced textually as a double.

pi is a float constant initialized from a double, and thus lose some precision bits (see IEEE754 specs).

For more details, pi as a float is in fact stored as 0x40490625 which is 3.1410000324249267578125. pi1 is stored as 0x400920C49BA5E354, which is  3.1410000000000000142108547152

Comment: If `pi` as a `float` is greater than `3.141`, how come `printf` converts `4*40*pi` to `125.639999` implying a value below `125.64`?

Answer (score 2):

In C floating-point literals are of type `double` unless you attach the suffix `f` (float) or `L` (long double)

So in the first part (`4*10*pi`) 3.141 is a `double` value that's cast down to float precision and stored in `const float pi`, then the expression `4*10*pi` will be done in `float` precision. OTOH in `4*10*pi1` the macro is substituted directly as a string and then calculated from `double`. That's why it's different

See [floating constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant)

Answer (score 0):

Just to reinforce what @Joel and @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc responses, consider the following snippet

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define pi1 3.141

const float pi = 3.141;

int main()
{

printf("foo"); // Just to mark assembly output

printf("4*10*pi == %f\n", 4*10*pi);

printf("4*10*pi1 == %f\n", 4*10*pi1);

float a = 4*10*pi;
float b = 4*10*pi1;
printf("%f %f\n", a, b);

}
```

And the assembly generated by gcc (4.8.1):

```
    .file   "c.c"
    .globl  _pi
    .section .rdata,"dr"
    .align 4
_pi:
    .long   1078527525
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
LC0:
    .ascii "foo\0"
LC3:
    .ascii "4*10*pi == %f\12\0"
LC5:
    .ascii "4*10*pi1 == %f\12\0"
LC7:
    .ascii "%f %f\12\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB6:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $48, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _printf

    flds    LC1
    flds    LC2
    fmulp   %st, %st(1)
    fstpl   4(%esp)
    movl    $LC3, (%esp)    
    call    _printf

    fldl    LC4
    fstpl   4(%esp)
    movl    $LC5, (%esp)
    call    _printf

    flds    LC1
    flds    LC2
    fmulp   %st, %st(1)
    fstps   44(%esp)
    movl    LC6, %eax
    movl    %eax, 40(%esp)
    flds    40(%esp)
    flds    44(%esp)
    fxch    %st(1)
    fstpl   12(%esp)
    fstpl   4(%esp)
    movl    $LC7, (%esp)
    call    _printf

    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE6:
    .section .rdata,"dr"
    .align 4
LC1:
    .long   1078527525
    .align 4
LC2:
    .long   1109393408
    .align 8
LC4:
    .long   -1030792151
    .long   1079994613
    .align 4
LC6:
    .long   1123764142
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.1"
    .def    _printf;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

I put extra `printfs`to help locating things. Now look how te values are constructed in a different manner:

For `4*10*pi`, two floats are loaded from FPUs and for `4*10*pi1` only one (there is no multiplication). I believe this will lead to the float/double convertion issues already cited.

I am not an assembler expert, but I think these snippets can help to understand what is happening or at least clarify that the two approaches to float multiplication dont´t lead to the same assembly.